# Python define method of class outside of class

Tags: python, class, structure

We are currently porting a MATLAB project to Python and thinking about the structure of the classes as we do not want to port the structure from MATLAB to Python but rather ensure that we design in in the most Pythonic way possible.

We have identified a class *X* that has several methods and later on we want to add new methods that work on objects of type *X*. It would make sense to make these new methods part of *X*, but we don't want to redefine *X* every time. Also, some of those methods are experimental and we would like to avoid adding them and in a later version remove them again.

What would be the Pythonic way to deal with this? We thought about adding new static methods in other classes *Y*,*Z* that can take *X* as an argument.

Comment: "We thought about adding new static methods in other classes Y,Z that can take X as an argument." Why use static methods? Just write regular functions.

Comment: "It would make sense to make these new methods part of X, but we don't want to redefine X every time" I don't understand why you just don't add them to the definition of X? You have to write the code *anyway*. But you can always write a method *after* the class defintion, `def foo(self): return whatever` then `X.foo = foo`. Although, this might be a bit confusing if it is spread around all over the project.

Comment: Export? You can write those functions wherever you see fit. If it is another module or the same module is up to you. But again, it isn't clear to me why you don't just add them to the class definition. Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: Perhaps, another thing to say is that we want to give other users the opportunity to use our project. Provide them with a set of methods/functions that work on our object of type X without including all of them in X. We want to avoid adding and removing methods from X too often.

Comment: OK then just using some functions seems like a reasonable solution

Comment: Can you make a subclass?